# Proving discontinuity at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I would like to prove that the function below is discontinuous at $x=0$. $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{for }  x\neq 0\\
0 & \text{for } x=0\end{cases}$$

What I have so far is this: (not much)

$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-0\right|=\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|$$

I'm not sure how to proceed. I think I need to think of some sort of bound that is helpful. I know that $|\sin(\cdot)|\leq1$, but I'm not sure how to use this fact properly. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Recall that if a function is continuous at the origin, it is also sequentially continuous.
2. Now consider the following sequence: $x_n = \dfrac1{n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2}$ and conclude what you want.

Comment: What does sequentially continuous mean?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan [Sequential continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences) means: Given any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \to x$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. In metric spaces, both the notions of continuity (i.e., the $\epsilon-\delta$ and sequential continuity) are equivalent.

Comment: Intuitively it means your function $f$ maps a convergent sequence to another convergent sequence. This makes sense because your $f$ is continuous which "preserves" the convergence.

Answer (score 0):

For a function be to continuous at a point,we must have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c^{+}} f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow c^{-}} f(x)=f(c)$$
Note that in the given function, $$\lim{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \sin \frac{1}{x}$$
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \sin \frac{1}{x}$ will have a value between [-1,1],but we cannot determine that value. Similar is the case when x$\rightarrow$-$0$. But the value of the function at x=0 is 0. Hence 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x)\ne\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}} f(x)\ne f(0)$$
Hence the function is not continuous at x=0.